# Using cast3d in flash actionscript error:

Tags: flash

Im new to Flash and i am trying to put a model online and to do so im tryinf to use cast3D frame work. When i tried the first tutorial this error cropped up
: "1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: LoadEvent." the code area where the error happend:

```
private function cast3dLoadComplete(event: LoadEvent): void
    {
        trace("cast3dLoadComplete ");
        this.manipulator = new TrackBall(this.animator,this.stage,
                                 this.stage.stageWidth, this.stage.stageHeight,
                                 Manipulator.Y_UP);
                       this.loaded = true;
                       removeTimer();                                   
                      if (loader.loaderror.length)
                      {
            statusText.textColor = 0xff0000;                                
            statusText.text = loader.loaderror;            
                       }
                      else
                      {                                 
            statusText.visible = false;
                      }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the load Error event
     */     
    private function cast3dLoadError(event: LoadEvent): void
    {
        trace("cast3dLoadError ", event.message );
                    removeTimer();
        statusText.textColor = 0xff0000;                                
        statusText.text = event.message;
    }               
}
}
```

can someone tell me what the problem with the code?
thanks alot 
Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is telling you that it can't find the class `LoadEvent` which is part of the cast3D framework. I suspect that you are not including the cast3D swc which contains the classes.

It can be download from [here - cast3D SWC](http://cast3d.com/demos/tutorials/intro/cast3d.swc)

If you still have a problem then it will be how you are including their classes, and that method depends on if you are using the Flash IDE, Flash Develop or Flash Builder for example.

**EDIT:**

I'm using CS5 but should be similar on CS3, go to menu:

> Edit -> preferences -> Actionscript 3 -> Library Path -> browse for SWC

Should see a panel similar to this one below!

[image]

Comment: can you tell me how to install an swc on the flash cs3 pls?

Comment: ho sry for the late reply. Now that i installed the .swc it is now telling me with the same error on these component in cast3D action scripts  like for example on this one:public function get xnode(): DisplayObject3D { return _xnode; }